# Flatten multiple query results with same ID to single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm curious about something in a SQL Server database. My current query pulls data about my employer's items for sale. It finds information for just under 105,000 items, which is correct. However, it returns over 155,000 rows, because each item has other things related to it. Right now, I run that data through a loop in Python, manually flattening it out by checking if the item the loop is working on is the same one it just worked on. If it is, I start filling in that item's extra information. Ideally, the SQL would return all this data already put into one row.

Here is an overview of the setup. I'm leaving out a few details for simplicity's sake, since I'm curious about the general theory, not looking for something I can copy and paste.

Item: contains the item ID, SKU, description, vendor ID, weight, and dimensions.

AttributeName: contains attr_id and attr_text. For instance, "color", "size", or "style".

AttributeValue: contains attr_value_id and attr_text. For instance, "blue" or "small".

AttributeAssign: contains item_id and attr_id. This ties attribute names to items.

attributeValueAssign: contains item_id and attr_value_id, tying attribute values to items.

A series of attachments is set up in a similar way, but with attachment and attachmentAssignment. Attachments can have only values, no names, so there is no need for the extra complexity of a third table as there is with attributes.

Vendor is simple: the ID is used in the item table. That is:

```
select item_id, vendorName
from item
join vendor on vendor_id = item.vendorNumber
```

gets you the name of an item's vendor.

Now, the fun part: items may or may not have vendors, attributes, or attachments. If they have either of the latter two, there's no way to know how many they have. I've seen items with 0 attributes and items with 5. Attachments are simpler, as there can only be 0 or 1 per item, but the possibility of 0 still demands an outer left join so I am guaranteed to get all the items.

That's how I get multiple rows per item. If an item has three attrigbutes, I get either four or seven rows for just that item--I'm not sure if it's a row per name/value or a row per name AND a row per value. Either way, this is the kind of thing I'd like to stop. I want each row in my result set to contain all attributes, with a cap at seven and null for any missing attribute. That is, something like:

item_id; item_title; item_sku; ... attribute1_name; attribute1_value; attribute2_name; attribute2_value; ... attribute7_value
1; some random item; 123-45; ... color; blue; size; medium; ... null

Right now, I'd get multiple rows for that, such as (only ID and attributes):

ID; attribute 1 name; attribute 1 value; attribute 2 name; attribute 2 value
1; color; blue; null; null
1; color; blue; size; medium

I'm after the second row only--all the information put together into one row per unique item ID. Currently, though, I get multiple rows, and Python has to put everything together. I'm outputting this to a spreadsheet, so information about an item has to be on that item's row.

I can just keep using Python if this is too much bother. But I wondered if there was a way to do it that would be relatively easy. My script works fine, and execution time isn't a concern. This is more for my own curiosity than a need to get anything working. Any thoughts on how--or if--this is possible?

Comment: "*an MSSQL database, but that shouldn't matter*" that matters a lot. String aggregation (which is what you want) is a piece of cake in e.g. Postgres, but not in SQL Server. [Edit] your question and add some properly formatted sample data and the expected output (formatted _text_ please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want the first 7 attributes and you want to keep all of the logic in the SQL query, you're probably looking at using row_number. Subqueries will do the job directly with multiple joins, and the performance will probably be pretty good since you're only joining so many times.

```
select
  i.item_id,
  attr1.name as attribute1_name, attr1.value as attribute1_value,
  ...
  attr7.name as attribute7_name, attr7.value as attribute7_value
 from
  items i
  left join (
   select
      *, row_number() over(partition by item_id order by name, attribute_id) as row_number
     from
      attributes
   ) AS attr1 ON
   attr1.item_id = i.item_id
   AND attr1.row_number = 1
  ...
  left join (
   select
      *, row_number() over(partition by item_id order by name, attribute_id) as row_number
     from
      attributes
   ) AS attr7 ON
   attr7.item_id = i.item_id
   AND attr7.row_number = 7
```

Comment: I never knew row_number() existed. I think I follow, but want to check. You use the row_number() to get only row n of the same subquery? That is, the subquery is identical every time, except that you get only row n from it, where n goes from 1 to 7? A bit like indexing into an array? I'll have to try this!

Comment: @WCWedin -- you should put the attribute subquery in a CTE and then join to the same table each time.

Comment: Thanks again; this seems to work. I get some repeated values, but I'm wondering if they are repeated in the database, not duplicated in this query. I'll have to see if I can use similar logic to shrink my results even more, as I'm still getting an extra 32,000 rows from somewhere. Better than 51,000 extras plus extra Python code!

Comment: @Hogan, can you briefly explain how using a CTE would work? Like row_number(), I've never used CTEs before and am still reading about them. I know you'd place the "select ... from attribute..." part in one, but how would you make and call the CTE in a single query, using it multiple times?

Comment: @AH16 - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is @WCWedin's answer modified to use a CTE.

```
WITH attrib_rn as
(
  select
    *, row_number() over(partition by item_id order by name, attribute_id) as row_number
  from attributes
)
select
  i.item_id,
  attr1.name as attribute1_name, attr1.value as attribute1_value,
  ...
  attr7.name as attribute7_name, attr7.value as attribute7_value
from items i
left join attrib_rn as attr1 ON attr1.item_id = i.item_id AND attr1.row_number = 1
left join attrib_rn as attr2 ON attr2.item_id = i.item_id AND attr2.row_number = 2
left join attrib_rn as attr3 ON attr3.item_id = i.item_id AND attr3.row_number = 3 
left join attrib_rn as attr4 ON attr4.item_id = i.item_id AND attr4.row_number = 4 
left join attrib_rn as attr5 ON attr5.item_id = i.item_id AND attr5.row_number = 5
left join attrib_rn as attr6 ON attr6.item_id = i.item_id AND attr6.row_number = 6
left join attrib_rn as attr7 ON attr7.item_id = i.item_id AND attr7.row_number = 7
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I noticed in the seven joins, you use different row numbers, but you always compare to attr1. E.G. "left join attrib_rn as attr6 ON attr1.item_id = i.item_id AND attr1.row_number = 6". Did you mean to use attr6, or should it always compare to attr1? Sorry if that's a dumb question; I'm still learning the finer points of SQL and want to make sure I have this right. Thanks.

Comment: @AH16 not a dumb question -- typo by me.

Comment: Thanks again everyone. I just put this CTE into my query and ran it. Everything appears to work correctly, but the query now has less repeated code, which is great. I also learned some very useful information from this exchange. This is great!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can tackle this with a subquery containing 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER', and a few CASE statements to map the top 7 into columns.

A little tricky, but post your full query that returns the big list and I'll demonstrate how to transpose it.